# Merge the [commitment] and [commitment-phase] tags on Meta

Tags: support, tags, meta, synonym-request

On Meta, we have the [commitment](/questions/tagged/commitment) tag and the [commitment-phase](/questions/tagged/commitment-phase) tag.
The first has 24 questions, all of which refer to the commitment phase of a new SE site.
The second has 107 questions, also all about the commitment phase of a new SE site.

I suggest we make "commitment" a synonym of "commitment-phase". The latter name is clearer, has a tag wiki, and over 4 times as many questions.